# how to get multiple libraries from the same project in cmake in my project

Tags: c++, build, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a project like this:

```
main
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- src
   |- api_1
   |  |- CMakeLists.txt (#1)
   |  |- api_1.h
   |  |- api_1.cpp
   |
   |- api_2
      |- CMakeLists.txt (#2)
      |- api_2.h
      |- api_2.cpp
```

When I compile the probject, I would like to obtain the following objects
as a result:

```
executable
libapi_1.so / libapi_1.a
libapi_2.so / libapi_2.a
```

The project currently builds `libapi_1.so`/`libapi_1.a`, but it does not build the other two. Due to the very high complexity of the probject and obscure naming, I am unable to understand where / how appropriately modify the main-level `CMakeLists.txt` in order to get an additional `.so / .a` file.

Can someone provide me with clear instructions on what is needed?

Comment: probably you are missing an `add_subdirectory` command?

Comment: @ErniBrown all `CMakeLists.txt` are properly linked. What is missing is the proper configuration to ask `cmake` to build the second target, which I am not sure how to write.

Comment: can you please post a minimal part of your code?

Comment: @ErniBrown I am afraid I do not have the legal rights to do so

Answer (score 1):

You can setup 2 (or more) projects in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(FullProject)
# config...
add_executable(exec1 ${sources_files}) # This line will create a new executable target
target_link_libraries(exec1 lib_you_need)
# config exec1...

# Now defines another target which is a library
add_library(lib1 ${sources_files}) # This line will create a new library target
target_include_directories(lib1 PRIVATE path_you_need)
```

When you'll build, you'll have 2 target: exec1 and lib1 and you can build the one you want using:

```
cmake --build . --target your_target # exec1 or lib1
```

or

```
make your_target # exec1 or lib1
```

Comment: Thank you Adrien for your help. The question here is how to add two separate libraries `lib1` and `lib2`. Which sources does one need, which sources does the other need? what is the `PRIVATE` tag in your answer?

Comment: I guess you should learn cmake basis. The lines you need is `  add_library(api_1 api_1.cpp api_1.h) ` . Same with api_2. Just ignore the target_XXX if you don't know what they are